# ¿Cómo puedo realizar un cambio de estilo de css utilizando los select en react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Hola estoy empezando con react y he estado buscando ejemplos por internet para poder cambiar el color de un div mediante un select y no se como hacer para pasar los valores del select a dicho div.

Comment: En react tienen la propiedad style para ponerle por dinamico por codigo o puedes usar react jss  o cambiar de nombre de clases de css (ej: activo,inactivo)

Answer (score 0):

Una opción es la siguiente:

```
<div style={{ backgroundColor: colorSeleccionadoPorElSelect }}></div>
```

en ese caso la propiedad que se le está pasando al `backgroundColor` ya debería existir en tu estado con un color por defecto, y en el select solamente mutas ese estado.